# KDE Plasma desktop not recognizing screen edges

Tags: linux, kde-plasma-5

I love plasma (5.8.3 Neon on a Samsung rf711), but my desktop behaves like I have another monitor to the right of my screen.  My windows and mouse could disappear into this imaginary space.  Is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: Different distros customize KDE in different ways, so it might be helpful to add that information to your question (identify the model of your computer, also).  Also, is this behavior something that has always been there, or is it a recent development?  And if so, did it start after an identifiable event, like updates or a hardware change?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever is happening on your system is not normal behavior, and I can't replicate it.  Just shooting in the dark, here are a few things to check, which will at least rule some things out.

As a first step, there are two places to check in the `System Settings`.

**Display and Monitor:**

[image: Display and Monitor]

Click on `Multiple Monitors` and verify that it doesn't think there is another monitor there.

**Workspace Behavior:**

[image: Workspace Behavior]

Click on `Screen Edges`.  The monitor image has a button at each corner and in the middle of each side.  If you click on one of those buttons, a popup menu appears with settings for that portion of the screen edge.  I haven't explored the effect of every setting, but `No Action` should result in the cursor not doing anything unexpected at the edge.

**Panel:**

One other possibility I can think of to check -- the edges are standard places to park panels and widgets.  Cursor off to the right, then right-click.  See if anything pops up in the way of a settings screen, which might identify something hiding on the side.

**Desktop Effects:**

This might help identify where the cursor actually is if it is still on the desktop when it appears to be somewhere else.  Again from the `System Settings`, click on `Desktop Effects`.  Select the `All Effects` tab.  Near the top, in the `Accessibility` section, is a feature called `Track Mouse`.  Enable this.

[image: Desktop Effects]

If you click on the wrench symbol, you can see the default key combination to trigger this feature.  On my system, it's <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ("Meta" is the Windows key or the equivalent on a Mac keyboard).  When you can't see the cursor, pressing this key combination will produce a locating pattern around the cursor, which you will see if the cursor is hiding on the desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think it's fixed.  I use 5.8.3 neon on a Samsung rf711

Comment: @BijanGhavami-Kia, if you figured out what the problem actually was (or know what fixed it), consider posting an answer.  That will help others with a similar problem.  If one of the suggestions in this answer fixed it, it would be helpful to comment on what it was.

Comment: Thank you again. so I followed your first steps but I think the layout has changed a bit in 5.8.3 from the screenshits you're referncing, nonetheless it led me in the right direction, I went to display and monitor under settings and then the display tab. there you can click on both the laptop tab in the large main window or the vga 1-2, both highlighting the various options available for both. my problem was that the vga1-2 was clicked on as enabled... once disabled it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me although I had to switch on a tv that's connected but hasn't been on since reinstalling the operating system.
A better result than expected was obtained by figuring out what it was trying to do when the cursor vanished off to the right, and then I clicked and dragged the image of that second screen in monitor settings & repositioned it to represent where it physically is in the room. So, now when the cursor vanishes off the *appropriate* edge, it appears on that screen as a preference - effectively whistling up an instant 55" parking monitor in the process :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).